# distance Pure Math graduate programs?

Tags: education

I would like to go to a graduate school for pure mathematics, but I do not live where such programs exits. Furthermore, I can not move. Question:  Do any Universities have graduate program in pure math that is offered in distance learning format?

Comment: What do you hope to get out of graduate study?

Comment: I'll be very honest with you. Whatever distance or online school you choose, stay away from Phoenix Univ. It's an expensive papermill institution, don't waste your money on that.

Comment: A distance learning graduate program doesn't seem like a good idea. Probably most of the value of being in a graduate program comes from being immersed in a physical environment with your fellow grad students and professors.